# Update Statement in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

Update in Hive is available in 0.14 version.

But how to do the same in previous version of Hive.

Say I have below table in Hive-

```
EmployeeTable

EmpId  EmpName  EmpSal
1         A       200
2         B       150
3         C       123
```

I want to update the salary of `Empid 2 to 500`.  How will I do that in hive?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with typical update statement. But you can achieve using temp tables.

1. Create a temp table with the list of updated values alone.
2. Create another master table with the records by joining main table left outer join with previous temp table and select the updated values from second table.
3. Now truncate the records of main table.
4. Load the main table with master temp table data.